# basic html text form

Tags: javascript, html

I want a text form for entering a string which is later read by javascript.

```
<form style='margin:10px;'> 
Input Value: <input type="text" value="3" id="input" name="input"/>
</form>
```

I'm noticing that when I press enter while it's selected causes the page to be reloaded. This is not what I want. How do I make it not reload the page when the form is "submitted"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent ENTER keypress to submit a web form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585396/how-to-prevent-enter-keypress-to-submit-a-web-form)

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585396/how-to-prevent-enter-keypress-to-submit-a-web-form, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563062/jquery-prevent-form-submition-with-enter-key ...

Comment: Possible duplicates are actually: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=form+prevent+enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the `<form>` tags? They don't seem to be doing anything. If you remove them you will no longer get that submission behaviour when you hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing enter is submitting the form. You can use Javascript to prevent the form from being submitted - one way of doing that is by using a submit button:

```
<input type="submit" onsubmit="formhandle(); return false;">
```

Create a formhandle() function in Javascript to do the processing you want to do. Returning false should prevent the form from being posted back to the server - however, that doesn't always work. There's more detailed information on preventing default actions in browsers here:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to catch the form send with JScript and send it to the server with ajax

```
<form style='margin:10px;' id='formID'> 
Input Value: <input type="text" value="3" id="input" name="input"/>
</form>
```

the JQuery (you can use Prototype or pure JS if you want) code goes a litte something like this

```
$('#target').submit(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url, 
    data: data,
    success: success,
    dataType: dataType,
  });
  return false;
});
```

The return false prevents the page from reloading. The documentation can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)