# Restrict the Enter key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent form submission with enter key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563062/prevent-form-submission-with-enter-key)

In my project, I am trying to disable the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and give my own enter key function.(*which I havent done*)

The below function is working but whenever I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key inside the `TextBox` field, the content is adding to `div` (as needed) and also in the `TextBox` field, enter key function is happening (which I dont want). How to stop the enter Key function to run on the `TextBox` field? For clear understanding please see my comments in the below code.

**.aspx file** (*working*)

```
<asp:TextBox ID="msg" BackColor="Transparent" runat="server" BorderStyle="None"
                        TextMode="MultiLine" />
```

---

**jQuery** (*working*)

```
$('#msg').keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {

                //Shows the TextBox text in a Div, which I want to.
                chat.server.send($('#msg').val());  //also going one step down in TextBox field which I dont want to.

                $('#msg').val(''); //Clearing the Text in TextBox field

                //what should I add here to make the Enter Key work only for the DIV?
            }
        });
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/979686/1577396)

Comment: Yes, and see the duplicate question you've asked, just as a million other people have...

Comment: @Ian What good would `close` do after getting a good answer? :)

Comment: You should just check more carefully before you post a question.

Comment: @AbijeetPatro I searched alot before asking here. I dont know the keyword with what the [**`duplicate question`**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115639/196352) is.. BTW, Stack overflow is made for having Q & A's. and we should show research in our posts which I have done as you can see clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `e.preventDefault()`
like this

```
$('#msg').keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //Shows the TextBox text in a Div, which I want to.
                chat.server.send($('#msg').val());  //also going one step down in TextBox field which I dont want to.

                $('#msg').val(''); //Clearing the Text in TextBox field

                //what should I add here to make the Enter Key work only for the DIV?
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try using C# for validating in C# also. Just write the below function and call the function supplying parameter as this(have mentioned below)

```
public void disable_TextBox_Enter(Control parent)
    {
        foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
        {
            if ((c.Controls.Count > 0))
            {
                disable_TextBox_Enter(c);
            }
            else
            {
                if (c is TextBox)
                {
                    ((TextBox)(c)).Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "return (event.keyCode!=13);");

                }
                if (c is GridView)
                {

                    ((GridView)(c)).Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "return (event.keyCode!=13);");

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

U can give call to the function like this :

```
disable_TextBox_Enter(this);
```