# JQuery - Char(13) - New line / stop submit issue

Tags: jquery, html

I have a issue to capture the class for my address field.
I want to stop the enter key (char[13]) from submitting the form, which I seemed to have done. 
But as a exception for my text blocks, in this case a address field, I want to allow next line.

The problem is that if I run this code, **myClass** in the console is said to be undefined.
If I can capture the class name then I can perform the next step which is to allow "next line" for that object.

Am I going down the right track? In which case can someone please guide me. Or if the solution should be completely different, please advise me how.

```
$(window).keypress(function(event){
    var myClass = item.attr('class');
    if(myClass == 'addressClass'){
        if(keycode == '13') {
            /* Code for NextLine */
            event.preventDefault();
            console.debug('New Line and Prevent Submit.');
        }
        console.debug(myClass);
    }

    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13') {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.debug('Prevent Submit.');
    }
});
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563062/prevent-form-submission-with-enter-key

Comment: @MelanciaUK. But I dont understand why in the console the detected class is "undefined". That is where I get stuck.

Comment: Where the `item` came from? I can't see it declared anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item.attr('class')` is undefined cause "item" is undefined. Instead of `attr()`  try to use

```
if (item.hasClass('addressClass'))
```

and before that try to define

```
var item = $(event.target);
```

or bind keypress event to text inputs

Comment: Thanks. Worked nicely. Sorry but Im a bit new to JQuery and did not note the item not being defined.