# Prevent form submitting when pressing enter from a text input, using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am using Vue.js in my app and have a text input within a form

```
<div id="myVueForm">
<form>
   <input type="text" v-on="keyup:addCategory | key 'enter'">

   <!-- more form fields -->
   <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
</form>
</div>
```

In my Vue instance I have the following

```
new Vue({
    el: '#myVueForm',

    methods: {
        addCategory: function(e)
        {
           if(e) e.preventDefault();
           console.log("Added a new category, thanks!");
        }
    }
});
```

Despite the `preventDefault()` call, when a user presses enter whilst on the text input the form still submits (although the `addCategory()` method does fire). This behaviour can be demonstrated in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lr3yk13e/4/).

I know I can use jQuery to catch the event and prevent the submit, but I'd like to see if it's possible in Vue to do this as it seems quite a common usage.

Comment: I want to be able to submit the form, just not by pressing enter in this particular text input. And that doesn't change anything. You can remove the button altogether and the form will still submit on enter

Comment: Thank you for supplying a fiddle. Not enough people do that these days.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The submit is always fired on keydown. So use keydown instead of keyup.

```
<input type="text"  v-on="keydown:addCategory | key 'enter'">
```

Comment: @keydown.enter.prevent="addCategory"

Comment: this helped me `<input type="text" v-on:keydown.enter.prevent="addCategory">`

Comment: `@keyup.enter="addCategory"` can be also used. But do not forget about `@submit.prevent` on form element. Tested on Vue v2.6.11.

Answer (score 98):

Here's a solution for Vue.js 2.x:

```
<input type='text' v-on:keydown.enter.prevent='addCategory' />
```

Comment: Your edit was rejected, but it was more in line with the question. I couldn't figure out how to "accept" it, but I made the changes. Thanks @Leng.

Comment: There is no need to add the `addCategory` method, just `<input type='text' v-on:keydown.enter.prevent/>` is sufficient

Comment: This worked for me. Just to add, you must make sure that it is v-on:keydown.enter.prevent to make it work.

Answer (score 73):

why dont just disable the form submission ?

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent><input .../></form>
```

Comment: And for modern Vue: @submit.prevent

Comment: This won't work if you form only contains 1 element, then the input always gets submitted. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12123196/151237

Comment: Yes it will. It s not preventing the form to be submitted. It catch the event and prevent the default behavior of the browser form. Submit.prevent is like v-on:submit=(e) => e.preventDefault().

Answer (score 19):

**You can use for disable the submit event:**

```
<form @submit.prevent="">
```

**and then when you need to do a form submit use something like this:**

```
<button type="submit" @click="mySubmitMethod"> Send </button>
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use this:

HTML

```
<form name="..." @submit.prevent="onSubmitMethod">
```

JS

```
methods: {
  onSubmitMethod() {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Vue.js 1.0 you could do:

```
<input type="text" @keyup.enter.prevent="addCategory">
```

Comment: You need to use `@keydown`, otherwise the form will already have been submitted and you can't prevent it anymore.

Answer (score 10):

For those simply looking to prevent a form submitting on enter, but not wanting to trigger any method on the input, you can simply do:

```
<input type="text" @keypress.enter.prevent />
```

Or on a custom component include the `native` modifier:

```
<custom-input type="text" @keypress.enter.native.prevent />
```

Beautifully readable and succinct.

Answer (score 3):

This works

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="get_user" @keydown.enter.prevent = "">
```

Answer (score 2):

I had an edge case where an input was within a popup, and the popup was for only part of the form. I wanted to prevent enter from submitting the form while the popup was open, but not altogether. This worked:

```
<input type="text" @keydown.enter.prevent = "" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get event from the HTML and send it to Vue just to preventDefault like so:

HTML

```
<input type="text" v-on:keydown.13="my_method($event)">
```

JS

```
methods: {
    my_method(event){
        // do something
        if (event) event.preventDefault();
        if (event) event.stopPropagation();
    },
},
```

Answer (score 1):

i wrote a helper for this.

```js
export const preventFormSubmitOnEnter = {
  mounted() {
    let cb = event => {
      if (event) event.preventDefault();
    };
    if (this.$el.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "form") {
      this.$el.onsubmit = cb;
    } else {
      const forms = this.$el.getElementsByTagName("form");
      for (let i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
        const form = forms[i];
        if (form) form.onsubmit = cb;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Include this mixin in your vue component and it will automagically work.

here is an example (Im using ElementUI):

```
<template>
  <el-form :model="form" :rules="rules" ref="form">
    <el-form-item prop="reference">
      <el-input v-model="form.reference" placeholder="Your Reference"/>
    </el-form-item>
  </el-form>
</template>

<script>
import { preventFormSubmitOnEnter } from "./util";

export default {
  mixins: [preventFormSubmitOnEnter],
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        reference: ""
      },
      rules: {
        reference: [{ required: true, message: "Reference is required!" }]
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    validate() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.$refs.form.validate(valid => {
          this.$emit("on-validate", valid, this.form);
          resolve(valid);
        });
      });
    },
    validateField(prop) {
      this.$refs.form.validateField(prop);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```