# event prevent default not working within VueJS instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, preventdefault

I'm trying to disable a form submission when the **enter** key is pressed. The approaches I've tried are listed below with the code and example demo.

**[EXAMPLE OF PROBLEM HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbq7hf1v/)**

**Desired outcome:**
Focus on the input, press down -> down -> enter and it should log the index of the record you have selected and stop there.

**What's actually happening:**
It logs as expected, but then reloads the page immediately as the form submits.

HTML

```
<form action="/some-action" @submit.stop.prevent="prevent">
  <div class="auto-complete" v-cloak>
    <div class="ico-input">
      <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Enter text" @keyup.prevent="handleKeypress">
    </div>
    <ul class="raw auto-complete-results">
      <li v-for="r in results" @click="loadSelection($index)" v-bind:class="{'selected': selectedIndex == $index}"><span>{{ r.name }}</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
var autocomplete = new Vue({
  el: '.auto-complete',
  data: {
    results: [{name: 'swimming1'}, {name: 'swimming2'}, {name: 'swimming3'}, {name: 'swimming4'}, {name: 'swimming5'}, ],
    selectedIndex: -1,
  },
  methods: {
    handleKeypress: function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();

      var key = event.which;

      if ([38, 40].indexOf(key) > -1) //handle up down arrows.
        this.arrowNavigation(key);

      else if (key == 13) //handle enter keypress
        this.loadSelection(this.selectedIndex);

      return false;
    },

    arrowNavigation: function(key, target) {
      if (key == 38) //up
        this.selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex - 1 < 0 ? 0 : this.selectedIndex - 1;
      if (key == 40) //down
        this.selectedIndex = (this.selectedIndex + 1) > (this.results.length - 1) ? 0 : this.selectedIndex + 1;
    },

    loadSelection: function(index) {

      if (index < 0 || index > this.results.length)
        return false;

      var selection = this.results[index];
      console.log("loading selection", index,selection);
    },

    prevent: function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    },
  }
})
```

I've tried various syntax approaches on both form/input (switching `submit` for `keyup` on the input)

- v-on:submit="prevent"
- @submit
- @submit.stop
- @submit.prevent
- @submit.stop.prevent="prevent"

I've also tried calling the following from with in the 2 event handlers aswell as returning false from them both.

- event.preventDefault()
- event.stopPropagation()

The form still triggers a page reload no matter what I try. I can't see anything obviously wrong so I turn to stackoverflow to guide my eyes.

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same problem. In my case, I'm parsing the form from an external source back into Vue. I guess in this case it doesn't recognize the form? This is strange, since if I set a breakpoint in the Vue file, it hits the breakpoint in Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12123196/1339840) to another question suggests that forms with a single input element always get submitted, not matter what you do.

And indeed adding another input (and hiding it) helped.

https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/Lbq7hf1v/1/

```
<div class="ico-input">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Enter text" @keyup.prevent="handleKeypress">
  <input type="text" hidden style="display:none;">
</div>
```

Browsers are stupid.

Answer (score 2):

Note that, **anything outside of the `el` that you use to reference your Vue instance will not be recognized by vue** no matter how correctly you define your event modifiers on your elements.

In your example you are referring to your Vue instance through the `.auto-complete` element which is a child of the `form` element which the `submit` event is bound to by default. Any event modifiers added to your `form` will never take effect. Try wrapping all your HTML in a div and reference vue through that, like so:

#### HTML

```
<div id="app">
    <!-- HTML/Vue Directives/Mustache here -->
    <form action="/some-action" @submit.stop.prevent="prevent"> 
        ... rest of your code ...
    </form>
</div>
```

#### JS:

```
var autocomplete = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: { 
        ... rest of your js code ...
})
```

Also [Vue devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) can be very useful when debugging such situations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

> `<form @submit.prevent>`

Works for Vue2

Answer (score 0):

Try @keydown.enter.prevent
I was having the same problem but I was using keyup

```
<input type="text" @keydown.enter.prevent="doSomething" />
```

You don't have to have a method either if you just want to stop the form from submitting just put @keydown.enter.prevent without a method.

```
<input type="text" @keydown.enter.prevent />
```