# how to use onclick in addeventlistener to prevent form data to be submitted?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This is just some part of my code .the thing which I am not understanding is how to use onclick in my html to prevent my php file from running. I have html file where my input is button type and I am using DOM2 that is `.addeventlistener`

```
function checku(event) {

    var start=event.currentTarget;
    var warning="";
    if(start.name=="pressed"){
        alert("sdf");
         var temp=document.getElementById("form");
    }
    else
        var temp=start;

        var size=temp.length;

    for(var i=0;i<size;i++) {
        //alert(temp[i].name);

        if(temp[i].name=="Email"){


            var re = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+@+[a-zA-Z]+?\.[a-z]{2,3}$/; 
            var len=temp[i].value.length;
            var t=re.test(temp[i].value)

            if(t==true||len==0){
                document.getElementById("user").innerHTML="";
                //  Email.style.color="black";
                if(len==0){
                    warning+="Email Address cannot be empty, ";
                    //return false;
                }
                //return true;

             } else {
                 user.style.fontStretch="condensed";
                 user.style.color="red";
                 user.style.fontWeight="600";
                 user.style.fontFamily="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif";
                 //  Email.style.color="red";
                 document.getElementById("user").innerHTML="It should contain @ and .com or.ca ";
                 warning+="Email Address, ";
                 //return false;
             }
        }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Your `temp` variable is not available in outside block.

Comment: actually the problem is the php file runs anyway regardless of the inputs being valid or inavalid         

form id="form" method="POST" action="signup.php">

Comment: why your tag question is only php? I see only javascript code

Comment: I actually I only uploaded the js
I thought only the js needs to be changed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent form submission with enter key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563062/prevent-form-submission-with-enter-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
div.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `button` inside your `form` tag, when clicked, will trigger the `submit` event and submit the form to the URL specified in the `action` attribute of the `form`.

If you are adding an `event` to carry out validation or other stuff, make sure that you change your button's `type` attribute to `button` i.e. `<button type='button'>Submit</button>`